# Finding non-monetised YouTube videos

Tags: youtube, search, ads

Is there any way to find YouTube videos which do not (currently) contain [overlay or video advertising](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2467968?hl=en-GB) - that is, non-monetised videos?

<sub>The only way I have found is to play the video to see if an advert appears.</sub>